# Why is my header-bar overlapping scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overlapping

I've tried looking at already existing questions but none of the solutions in them worked for me. Basically, my header-bar(which is supposed to be across the entire screen) is overlapping the scrollbar - and I can't seem to get it UNDER the scrollbar, which is what I want.

[image: Overlapping]

http://jsfiddle.net/9cnXN/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/9cnXN/2/embedded/result/

This is using Rockmelt as browser.
I can also confirm problem on FireFox latest version as well as Chrome.

Comment: @ZoltanToth Sorry! I added what browser I'm using in the original post :)

Comment: weird.. can't reproduce neither in FF nor in Webkit

Comment: Added a new example in jsfiddle. Now it's visible in the embedded example there! Can you reproduce the error now?

Comment: You want a fixed header and footer with a scrollable content area, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/9cnXN/3/ ?

Comment: WOW, that was really fast! Thank you soo much :D That's exactly what I was looking for! If you post this as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the margins of the scrollable area to be exactly the height of the header and footer bar - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cnXN/3/)

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 44px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you once again, Zoltan! :) Really, I should've thought about this, it's so obvious once you know it. Thanks!